# Database in Android similar to plist in iPhone

Tags: android, database, persistence

Is there any back end available for Android apps other than SQLITE. Is there anything similar to iPhone PLIST or BlackBerry Persistence store  available for developing android app?

Thanks,
Adarsh V C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep : [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Take a look at : [the Android doc for Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

If you want to store values that should never be modified, you could just create a class with static final fields ( `public static final String myKey = "myValue"` )

Comment: Thank you louiscoquio. A Quick question. Is this SharedPreferences feasible to store records having 10 or more fields?

Comment: AFAIK there is no reason to limit SharedPreferences to 10 records.But be aware, the user can remove all SharedPreferences.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My question is can we use SharedPreferences to store records that have 10 or more fields. Means For example If a SQLIITE table named user have 10 or more fields like username,password,zipcode etc.. Then We can use SharedPreferences in place of SQLITE Table or not?

Comment: SharedPreferences is a Map stored in the device, so it can't replace sqlite table. It can be used to store one username, one password, one zipcode, one address,...If you want to register multiple accounts for example, I guess you should use sqlite table instead.

Comment: Yup . I just need to confirm that. Thank you and a +1. :)